# GROUP BY ColA having various column values in ColB

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want to select all distinct values of `ColA`, which have at least one out of each element from a given set of values in `ColB`

Sample table:

```
ColA  ColB
A     1
A     2
B     1
C     2
C     2
D     NULL
E     1
E     2
E     2
E     3
```

Desired result: all ColA values which have at least once 1 and 2 as ColB values:

```
A (has 1 once, has 2 once)
E (has 1 once, has 2 twice)
```

I know I have to use `GROUP BY` but don't know the exact aggregate function, which one should I use?

```
SELECT ... FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ColA
HAVING at_least_values(ColB, (1, 2)) // something like this
```

What's a good solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the values in the `having` clause using conditional logic:

```
having sum(case when colB = 1 then 1 else 0 end) >= 1 and
       sum(case when colB = 2 then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`intersect` is one way to do it.

```
SELECT ColA FROM MyTable where colB = 1
intersect 
SELECT ColA FROM MyTable where colB = 2
```

Comment: Great solution. INTERSECT really highlights the set based nature of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  You can filter for all 1s and 2s in ColB using the WHERE clause.  Then filter for records with both values (DISTINCT COUNT of 2) using the HAVING clause.

```
-- Return all ColA with a ColB of 1 and 2.emphasized text
SELECT
    ColA
FROM
    Mytable
WHERE
    ColB IN (1, 2)    -- Only 1s and 2s required.
GROUP BY
    ColA
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT ColB) = 2    -- Must have both values.
```

Alternatively you could use the [INTERSECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operator.  This allows you to find records that appear in both queries.  See example below.

```
SELECT
    ColA
FROM
   Mytable
WHERE
    ColB = 1
GROUP BY
   ColA

INTERSECT

SELECT
    ColA
FROM
   Mytable
WHERE
    ColB = 2
GROUP BY
   ColA
```